# Getting the opposite outputs from Tensorflow learn with OR gate

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

Given the DNN (simple case of multilayered perceptron) with 2 hidden layers of 5 and 3 dimensions respectively, I am training a model to recognize the OR gate.

Using tensorflow learn, it seems like it's giving me the reverse output and I have no idea why:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[5, 3], n_classes=2)

or_input = np.array([[0.,0.], [0.,1.], [1.,0.]])
or_output = np.array([[0,1,1]]).T

classifier.fit(or_input, or_output, steps=0.05, batch_size=3)
classifier.predict(np.array([ [1., 1.], [1., 0.] , [0., 0.] , [0., 1.]]))
```

[out]:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 0])
```

If I'm doing it "old-school", without the `tensorflow.learn` as follows, I get the expected answer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Parameters
learning_rate = 1.0
num_epochs = 1000

# Network Parameters
input_dim = 2 # Input dimensions.
hidden_dim_1 = 5 # 1st layer number of features
hidden_dim_2 = 3 # 2nd layer number of features
output_dim = 1 # Output dimensions.

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, input_dim])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [hidden_dim_2, output_dim])

# With biases.
weights = {
    'syn0': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim, hidden_dim_1])),
    'syn1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_dim_1, hidden_dim_2])),
    'syn2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_dim_2, output_dim]))
}


biases = {
    'b0': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_dim_1])),
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_dim_2])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_dim]))
}


# Create a model
def multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer 1  + sigmoid activation function
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['syn0']), biases['b0'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer 2 + sigmoid activation function
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['syn1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)
    # Output layer
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['syn2']) + biases['b2']
    out_layer = tf.nn.sigmoid(out_layer)
    return out_layer

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.sub(y, pred) 
# Or you can use fancy cost like:
##tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

or_input = np.array([[0.,0.], [0.,1.], [1.,0.]])
or_output = np.array([[0.,1.,1.]]).T

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        batch_x, batch_y = or_input, or_output # Loop over all data points.
        # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        #print (c)

    # Now let's test it on the unknown dataset.
    new_inputs = np.array([[1.,1.], [1.,0.]])
    feed_dict = {x: new_inputs}
    predictions = sess.run(pred, feed_dict)
    print (predictions)
```

[out]:

```
[[ 0.99998868]
 [ 0.99998868]]
```

**Why is it that I am getting the reversed output using `tensorflow.learn`?** Am I doing something wrongly using the `tensorflow.learn`?

**How do I get the `tensorflow.learn` code to produce the same output as the "old-school" tensorflow framework?**

Comment: Do you expect your DNN to learn from 3 samples? Well... i think that's a very optimistic approach. Nonetheless i think that you are comparing different architectures. Manually you are introducing sigmoidal activations, but i expect DNNClassifier's default-activation to be ReLu. Maybe there are other differences as well. Did you run both multiple times with different seeds? I think you should do this.

Comment: Actually in the case of an OR gate, 3 samples should be fine. there's only a maximum of 4 data points and the only missing one from the training point is `[1,1]`

Comment: Yeah, but in my opinion this results in a very huge dependency regarding meta-parameters. Did you try the multiple runs with different parameters (or at least seeds). I think it would be interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specify the right argument for `steps` you get the good results:

```
classifier.fit(or_input, or_output, steps=1000, batch_size=3)
```

Result:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 1])
```

---

#### How does `steps` work

The `steps` argument specifies the number of times you run the training operation. Let me give you some examples:

- with `batch_size = 16` and `steps = 10`, you will see a total of `160` examples
- in your example, `batch_size = 3` and `steps = 1000`, the algorithm will see `3000` examples. In fact, it will see 1000 times the same 3 examples you provided

So, `steps` is not the number of epochs, it is the number of times you run the training op, or the number of times you see a new batch.

---

#### Why is `steps = 0.05` allowed?

In the `tf.learn` code, they don't check if `steps` is an integer. They just run a while loop checking that (at [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5161e4c51b994b3feb93cdb851479c29a3450f31/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py#L332)):

```
last_step < max_steps
```

So if `max_steps = 0.05`, it will behave the same as if `max_steps = 1` (`last_step` is incremented in the loop).

Comment: Tuning the `steps` did the job but there's still no clear idea why. BTW, is it right that the `steps` parameter means the no. of epochs in training? If so, shouldn't it be an integer, any idea why did `tensorflow` allowed me to do 0.05 steps?

Comment: Thanks Olivier for the detailed explanation !!